# Why does this work?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I was googling trying to find a way to call `Control.DataBindings.Add` without using a string literal but getting the property name from the property itself, which I think would be less error prone, at least for my particular case, since I normally let Visual Studio do the renaming when renaming a property. So my code would look something like `DataBindings.Add(GetName(myInstance.myObject)...` instead of `DataBindings.Add("myObject"...`. So I found this:

```
    static string GetName<T>(T item) where T : class
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        if (properties.Length != 1) throw new Exception("Length must be 1");
        return properties[0].Name;
    }
```

That would be called, assuming I have a property called `One`, this way: `string name = GetName(new { this.One });` which would give me `"One"`. I have no clue why does it work and whether is safe to use it or not. I don't even know what that `new { this.One }` means. And I don't know on which case could it happens that `properties.Length` is not 1.

By the way, I just tested to rename my property `One` to `Two` and Visual Studio turned `new { this.One }` into `new { One = this.Two }`, which when used with the `GetName` function gave me `"One"`, which make the whole thing useless since the name I would be passing to `Control.DataBindings.Add` would be still "One" after renaming the property.

Comment: I can't believe VS is emitting `new { this.One }`, unless you using anonymous classes in the first place.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329138/how-to-make-databinding-type-safe-and-support-refactoring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new { this.One }` creates an instance of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with one Property, which is, because you didn't specify a name, called "One". That's why it works.

if you use `new { One = this.Two }`, you give the property the name "One". If you would leave out the part "One = ", it would work again.

However, the method you are using might be misunderstood if one does not know how it's intended to be used and if one does not call it using an anonymous type.

There is another way if you don't want to use string literals, here is one of the examples you can find on the web:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/57234/Getting-Property-Name-using-LINQ.aspx

Comment: Guess I'll have to stick to string literals :(

Comment: You don't have to. See my edit for another, probably more clean way.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC makes extensive use of anonymous types to specify things like HTML attributes.

Answer (score 3):

No, you do not have to stick to string literals:

```
public static class ControlBindingsCollectionExtensions
{
   public static void Add<T>(this ControlBindingsCollection instance, Expression<Func<T, object>> property)
    {
        var body = property.Body as UnaryExpression;
        var member = body.Operand as MemberExpression;
        var name = member.Member.Name;
        instance.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Control.DataBindings.Add<MyClass>(m => m.MyProperty);
```