# WPF DataTemplate for safe DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf

Could someone provide short example code for this answer: [One way to get feedback if your bindings are broken, is to create a DataTemplate and declare its DataType to be the type of the ViewModel that it binds to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4980507/1296687)

How to refactor for example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Application.Views.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Application.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">        
        <Grid>    
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Button Content="Press me!" Command="{Binding Path=ServiceReadCommand}" />
                <ListBox Width="200" Height="200" DataContext="{Binding ReactiveList}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>        
</UserControl>
```

Control is then used in ReactiveUi as:

```
// Navigate to the opening page of the application
Router.Navigate.Execute(new TestViewModel(this));
```

in AppBootStrapper.

Answer (score 0):

What that answer is referring to is called an **Implicit DataTemplate**. That's a DataTemplate that contains a data type, but no key property to identify it by.

Whenever WPF goes to draw a non-UI object in the Visual Tree, it checks to see if any template has been defined for that object first.

For example, if you had the following in your `<XXXX.Resources>` somewhere

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TestViewModel}">
    <local:TestView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then anywhere WPF tried to draw a `TestViewModel` object in the UI, it would draw it using the `TestView`.

A `ContentControl` is frequently used to insert code objects in the UI because the `.Content` property can be any object, including ViewModels or Models.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
```

The question you linked though was about how to make the bindings themselves type safe and support refactoring, and this would not do that. For example, if you had `<TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" />` and you wanted to rename `Name` to `GroupName`, Visual Studio would not know that the `.Name` property is linked to the renamed `.GroupName` property.

Comment: If I put `<Grid />` into `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:TestViewModel}" >` then I can use Resharper refactoring. Q is how to replace UserControl by that "template" and how to use it. If I put `<DataTemplate>` into `<X.Resources>` Reactive binding don't work.

Comment: I have not used Resharper refactoring, so can't help you there. In this case, you could either keep your `UserControl` and just have the DataTemplate draw any `TestViewModel` object using the UserControl `TestView` like I have in the code samples, or you could copy/paste the contents of your UserControl (starting at the `<Grid>`) into the DataTemplate. DataTemplates are typically defined in `<Window.Resources>`, although you can move them further down if you only want them to apply to a smaller scope, such as `<ContentControl.Resources>`