# Bind button content to a variable

Tags: c#, button, uwp

I have the following in XAML:

```
<Button Content="{Binding KB.Text}" />
```

KB is an instance of the following class:

```
public class ButtonText
    {
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return "Button";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have KB defined as global variable in the code behind of the page, the button content is showing empty when running the project, how would I achieve this? The button content should be retrieved by KB.Text

Comment: can you show what you are setting to your `MainWindow.DataContext`?

Comment: `this.DataContext = this;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure that your "KB" object is initialized (not null).
- You might have missed "this.DataContext = this" in your main function
- Make sure your KB is property

This works for me:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        KB = new ButtonText();
    }

    public ButtonText KB { get; }

}
public class ButtonText
{
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "Button";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I wrote the first solution having in mind WPF, took me a while to figure there's a "UWP" tag.

In UWP, if you want to bind something to the code behind of the designer itself (*xaml.cs), you should use "x:Bind" instead of "Binding".

See the [link about x:Bind vs Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399720/8053420)

In short, your xaml should look like so:

```
<Button Content="{x:Bind KB.Text}"/>
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work for me, could it because my main class inherits from Page instead of Window? or maybe I need to define a xmlns property? I've tried it on a new project as well.

Comment: @Ham.Abdu2 Sorry, I forgot it's UWP and not WPF. I updated my answer

Comment: How this is supposed to work? The KB is initialized after setting the datacontext, therefore UI won't have correct value. Also without INotifyPropertyChanged further changes to KB won't notify UI.