# Xamarin.Forms: How To Avoid Hard-Coding a String in MVVM Bindings

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, I am creating an MVVM binding for the `Button`'s `CommandProperty`.

Is there a way to avoid hard-coding the string for the property name?

This way works, but I want to avoid hard-coding a string:

```
var submitButton = new Button();
submitButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "SubmitButtonPressed");
```

I've found similar answers on StackOverflow that show how to perform type-safety in WinForms, but Xamarin.Forms uses a different binding engine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Databinding type safe and support refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329138/how-to-make-databinding-type-safe-and-support-refactoring)

Comment: Great point! It's similar, but Xamarin.Forms uses a different binding mechanism than WPF

Comment: Good to know. I'll read more about how it works on Xamarin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways that you can use to implement type-safety and avoid hard-coding strings when creating MVVM bindings in Xamarin.Forms

## First Way

Reference the View Model and use `nameof` instead.

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
BindingContext = myViewModel;

var submitButton = new Button();
submitButton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, nameof(MyViewModel.SubmitButtonPressed));
```

## Second Way (Deprecated)

Include the View Model as the `Type` for the `SetBinding` method and use a `Func`.

```
var myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
BindingContext = myViewModel;

var submitButton = new Button();
submitButton.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Button.CommandProperty, vm => vm.SubmitButtonPressed);
```

When using this technique, if you refactor the name of the `SubmitButtonPressed`  property in the view model, the new name will percolate up to your view! *And* you never have to worry about typos again!

## Update, 23 Jan 2017

As of Xamarin.Forms v2.3.4, the "Second Way" listed above, setting data bindings using generics, is deprecated. The Xamarin.Forms team explained to me that the generic way was eventually converted to the non-generic way at runtime, and it induced great costs because Expression-parsing is an expensive, CPU-intensive, operation causing performance degradation on mobile devices.

Comment: Any hope for those of us using xaml for layouts?

Comment: You'll still need to use a hard-coded string when creating bindings in XAML. You could use x:Name to create a name for the XAML property, then create the type-safe Binding in code-behind.